# C Programming How to read a string into an array and print it back out properly?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm in the process of learning C and I am going through the book "C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition". I am on Chapter 8 programming project 6 if anyone has the book.

The project wants me to create a program that takes a message from the user as input, make the message upper case, change some of the characters to numbers, and then print it out. I got the program to work with the example message(Hey dude, C is rilly cool) but I'm not sure how to get the program to handle a message of any length without using a variable array or dynamic array because the book hasn't went that far yet. Any help would be appreciated.

My code below

```
/* Translates a message entered by the user into BIFF speak */

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE ((int) (sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0])))

int main(void)
{
        char message[25];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                message[i] = 0;

        printf("Enter message: ");
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                scanf("%c", &message[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                if ((message[i] >= 'a')  && (message[i] <= 'z'))
                        message[i] = message[i] - 32;
                switch (message[i]) {
                        case 'A':
                                message[i] = '4';
                                break;
                        case 'B':
                                message[i] = '8';
                                break;
                        case 'E':
                                message[i] = '3';
                                break;
                        case 'I':
                                message[i] = '1';
                                break;
                        case 'O':
                                message[i] = '0';
                                break;
                        case 'S':
                                message[i] = '5';
                                break;
                }
        }

        printf("In B1FF-speak: ");
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                printf("%c", message[i]);
        }
        printf("!!!!!!!!!!\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you must use you own case conversion code, consider `message[i] = message[i] - 'a' + 'A';` rather than `message[i] = message[i] - 32;`.  It better self-documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses sizeof to determine the max length of the intput message, which is scanned using scanf.

In C strings are 0 terminated, so you have some options since your string will have to be smaller than the message[] you provide to place it in.

Firstly you have to allocate as much memory in message[] as you need to grab the largest possible message. You can then get the size of the message by using strlen(message) which will count how many characters until the first 0, and use that in your method, or you can simply break; out of your loop once the character is 0 (the 0 terminator indicating the end of the string). You could do that by changing in your for loop (i > SIZE) to ((i < SIZE) && (message[i] != 0)).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to figure it out after you answer. I just had the for loop for getting input break if it hits '\n' then used the strlen function in the for loop for output. Then I made the array 1000 characters and it seems to be working for anything that doesn't have a new line in it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [getline(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Getline uses a `malloc`'ed string (which you have to `free` afterwards). It will `realloc` that string so that it can always hold the incoming line regardless of how large it is.

(That is basically a kind of a dynamic-array solution, though. If you absolutely must have a fixed sized buffer that's not on the heap, then you can use [fgets(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to fill that buffer with (at best) a line from `stdin`. `fgets` will take care not to overflow your buffer.)

As far as upcasing characters is concerned, the standard library gives you [toupper(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper).

Also, note that if you want to be reading character by character, `getchar` might be a better choice than `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would use the functions to do this but the book didn't cover them so I was trying to do it with out them.